# Using Luxon, how do return a total count of days that are >= 30 days?

Tags: javascript, typescript, luxon

I have an array that looks something like this

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: '1', name: 'thing1', createdAt: '2022-09-21T16:26:02Z',
  },
  {
    id: '2', name: 'thing1', createdAt: '2022-11-21T16:20:20Z',
  },
];
```

What I want to do is iterate over this array and filter the ones that the condition `createdAt >= 30 days ago from today` and get the total count of that.

What I've tried was something like this:

```
// today is 11/21/22

const totalOverdueCount = arr.filter((item) => DateTime.fromISO(item.createdAt).diffNow('days').days >= 30).length
```

From my dataset, it *should* be returning a count of 1 (as of writing it is 11/21/22). However, I'm not getting that result. Am I using diffNow incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Since dates in dataset are in the past, `diffNow` returns negative values, you can simply update your condition to `<= -30` or use absolute value.

Updated code example:

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

const arr = [
  {
    id: '1', name: 'thing1', createdAt: '2022-09-21T16:26:02Z',
  },
  {
    id: '2', name: 'thing1', createdAt: '2022-11-21T16:20:20Z',
  },
];

const totalOverdueCount = arr.filter((item) => DateTime.fromISO(item.createdAt).diffNow('days').days <= -30).length
console.log(totalOverdueCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@3.1.0/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>
```